# How can I make it so different clients load unique rows each time (non-overlapping), without making user login sessions?

Tags: python, django, database

I have an app built in Django whose purpose is to be able to allow the user to customize a specific column of a database. Here is the current basic functionality:

- select 30 distinct rows from table_a.
- one row at a time, let user edit specific field.
- after each edit, send that row to table_b, to be retrieved again for final inspection before updating table_a.
- after the batch of 30 rows is completed and stored in table_b, retrieve them all from table_b for inspection.
- press the confirm button to update table_b with the edits that were inspected.

All of the above works just fine, and isn't the problem. The problem is that after the initial batch selection of 30 rows, another client could also potentially select some (or all) of those 30 rows for their batch.

This question isn't about the structure of the app as detailed above, it's about how to integrate keeping clients from working on the same rows under the current app architecture. But if you'd like to tear apart how it's built, please also explain how to do what I'm asking. Especially if that's necessary for what I need.

Below are the four views.py functions I'm using (select 30 from table_a, send individual row to table_b, select all from table_b for inspection, send all 30 inspected to update table_a).

```
@csrf_protect
def get_from_fim_table(request):
    if request.GET:
        if 'drugList' in request.GET:
            # retrieve fims from database
            fims = Fim.objects.select_for_update().filter(drug_type='').filter(verify=True).exclude(crib_name='')[:int(request.GET.get('numberOfDrugs'))]
            untyped_drugs = [fim.crib_name for fim in fims]
            urls = [fim.drug_type for fim in fims]
            number_of_drugs_in_batch = len(fims)
            number_of_drugs_left = len(Fim.objects.filter(drug_type='').filter(verify=True).exclude(crib_name='').distinct('crib_name'))
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data' : [untyped_drugs, urls, number_of_drugs_in_batch, number_of_drugs_left]}), content_type='application/json')
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data' : 'Error with request.GET'}), content_type='application/json')


@csrf_protect
def send_to_temporary_table(request):
    if request.POST:
        if 'drug_name' in request.POST and 'drug_type' in request.POST:
            drug_name = json.loads(request.POST['drug_name'])
            drug_type = json.loads(request.POST['drug_type'])

            new_temp_drug = TypesToVerify.create(drug_name, drug_type)
            new_temp_drug.save()

            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data' : 'Successfully stored drug and type into types_to_verify table.'}))


@csrf_protect
def get_from_temporary_table(request):
    if request.GET:
        unverified_drugs = [x.crib_name for x in TypesToVerify.objects.all()]
        unverified_drug_types = [x.drug_type for x in TypesToVerify.objects.all()]
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data' : [unverified_drugs, unverified_drug_types]}), content_type='application/json')
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data' : 'Error with request.GET'}), content_type='application/json')


@csrf_protect
def send_to_fim_table(request):
    if request.POST:
        if 'drug_list' in request.POST and 'type_list' in request.POST:
            drug_list = json.loads(request.POST['drug_list'])
            type_list = json.loads(request.POST['type_list'])

            for i in range(len(drug_list)):
                fims = Fim.objects.filter(verify=True).filter(crib_name=drug_list[i])
                for fim in fims:
                    fim.drug_type = type_list[i]
                    print('{} was assigned the type {}.'.format(drug_list[i], type_list[i]))
                    fim.save()

            # delete all rows in types_to_verify
            TypesToVerify.objects.all().delete()
            print('\nCleaned out types_to_verify table for next batch.\n')

            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data' : 'Successfully assigned types.'}))
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data' : 'There was an error getting the request on the server side.'}))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to lock the rows in the database once they're assigned to a user, and then unlock them when the user is finished with them. This could be accomplished by adding a `claimed` field to the model, but what if a user doesn't fully complete their edits? You could "unclaim" all of those objects when a user's session ends, but that seems a bit hairy.

Rather than flipping the `claimed` switch, I think you should add a `assigned_at` DateTimeField to the model. When a user gets their 30 rows from the database, save the objects to update their assigned_at field (if you set `auto_now=True` when creating the model).

Then, when you go to assign rows to a user, filter out potentially claimed rows by checking that their last assignment was more than `x` time ago (how long should it take until a user "times out" and releases the rows?). This can be accomplished using [range()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#range).

You'll need to be careful here, though. What if our first user returns after being timed-out and tries to continue editing? You can avoid this by actually assigning a user to the row as well by adding a foreign key to the model. After generating a list of "unclaimed" objects, save the user you've assigned to handle that row (`model.owner = request.user`). Then, when you receive the request to edit the row, verify the user sending the request actually "owns" that row:

```
if model.owner != request.user:
     return HttpResponse("You can't do that!", status=403)
```

Comment: Totally works for me. Thanks for your advice. I'll update this comment later with what I did exactly that made it work.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it.